# Изменение настроек по умолчанию при импорте изображений

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor, settings

В проектах при импорте картинок автоматически `Max Size` выставляется в значение `2048`, а `Compression` - `Normal Quality`.

[image]

Каждый раз мне придётся ставить их на `8192` и `High Quality`. Наверняка есть возможность изменить это в настройках. Я искал, но не нашёл.

---

*Может вы знаете, как менять этот параметр?*

Comment: Что будет если нажать на стрелку вниз или на андроида рядом со словом Default?

Comment: @Эникейщик стрелка вниз это значок "Скачать" (не знаю что он там делает). Он меняет те же самые настройки. но только для `PC, Mac & Linux Standalone` как там написано. А значок Андроида соответственно делает то же самое для Андроид. `Default` меняет всё сразу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно написать такой скрипт и положить в проект. Он будет срабатывать при каждом импорте. К примеру, такой скрипт при импорте любой текстуры выставит `Max Size` в `8192`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

namespace Suvitruf.Editor {
    class ImportPreProcessor : AssetPostprocessor {
        void OnPreprocessTexture() {
            // получаем ссылку на встроенный TextureImporter
            TextureImporter importer = (TextureImporter)assetImporter;

            // создаём новый экземпляр настроек
            TextureImporterSettings textureImporterSettings = new TextureImporterSettings();

            // читаем текущие настройки дефолтные
            // заполняем ими наши недавно созданные настройки
            importer.ReadTextureSettings(textureImporterSettings);

            // меняем Max Size
            textureImporterSettings.maxTextureSize = 8192;

            // применяем
            importer.SetTextureSettings(textureImporterSettings);
        }
    }
}
```

В Unity 2019 `TextureImporterSettings` не рекомендуется использовать. Нужно настройки для платформы задавать.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

namespace Suvitruf.Editor {
    class ImportPreProcessor : AssetPostprocessor {
        void OnPreprocessTexture() {
            // получаем ссылку на встроенный TextureImporter
            TextureImporter importer = (TextureImporter)assetImporter;

            // создаём новый экземпляр настроек
            TextureImporterPlatformSettings textureImporterSettings = new TextureImporterPlatformSettings();

            // читаем текущие настройки дефолтные
            // заполняем ими наши недавно созданные настройки
            importer.GetDefaultPlatformTextureSettings();

            // меняем Max Size
            textureImporterSettings.maxTextureSize = 8192;
            // устанавливаем HQ качество
            textureImporterSettings.textureCompression = TextureImporterCompression.CompressedHQ;

            // применяем
            importer.SetPlatformTextureSettings(textureImporterSettings);
        }
    }
}
```

Другой подход - написать скрипт для редактора, который будет рекурсивно прогонять все ваши текстуры в проекте и менять для них настройки.

Comment: Прежде чем использовать ваш метод я бы хотел спрашивать у поддержки. Пожалуйста подождите пару дней (может меньше).

Comment: @AltF4 ну как? )

Comment: Поддержка не отвечает, в интернете не нашёл другое решение. На данный момент ваше решение наилучший, но я продолжу искать и при нахождении ответа получше я буду обязан сменить галочку. Без обид, ок? 

Comment: @AltF4 всё нормально (:

Comment: Крутой ответ, редко кто в принципе говорит про (пре)процессоры ассетов.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker вообще мало кто использует возможности редактора. У нас в прошлых проектах очень много кастомных скриптов было для редактора, которые сильно упрощали жизнь.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica имхо, мало материала в сети, что от юнити, что от комьюнити, максимум, что можно найти - как сделать кастомное окно с кнопкой. Есть, конечно, крутые статьи, но их неприлично мало. Хотя сам недавно узнал, что с помощью редактора можно сделать практически что угодно, когда сел делать чисто редакторский проект для души :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker можно купить/скачать плагинов из Unity Store для редактора и там уже самому в коде разбираться и изучать.

Comment: Это да, но уже ни раз видел прямо гору косяков в таких проектах (разве что в визуальных редакторах кода типа PlayMaker и других не лазил). Как-то своим путем пошел по IMGUI через исходники Unity, естественно споткнулся десятки раз на этом IMGUI, жду не дождусь, когда пересяду на новый xml/css формат.